# Is "transitionable" a valid word?

Tags: is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

I want to say that a task should be made to be **transitionable**, meaning it should be easy to transition the task to another person without requiring an extensive amount of training. My spell checker does not accept it as a word, and even Google asks "Did you mean ***transition***?"

I think it's valid, being a construction of the verb **transition** and the suffix **-able**, but would like to get confirmation (or an alternative, if it's invalid) from experts before committing it to a written document.

The only results I find for **transitionable** are in the context of highly technical usage, like mathematics and computer animation.

Comment: You probably need ***transferable***: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transferable

Comment: What @Josh said. Absent further context, I'd understand ***transitionable*** as meaning ***capable of being transitioned***, where per OED the verb *transition* essentially means *To make or undergo a transition (from one state, system, etc. to or into another).* But nowadays it also has the very specific sense of transitioning *from one gender to another*, so my first thought would be that it means ***suitable for gender reassignment surgery***. (Probably *not* what OP intends! :)

Comment: Why don't you consult a dictionary? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Transitionable

Answer (score 3):

***Transition*** is recognized as a verb {editorial: alas!} but it probably hasn't become widely accepted as a *transitive* verb.

Dictionary.reference.com sayeth:

> **Transition**
>   verb (used without object)
>   4.
>   to make a transition:
>   He had difficulty transitioning from enlisted man to officer.
>   5.
>   to change from one gender identity to another or to align one's dress, behavior, etc., with one's gender identity:
>   My friend is transitioning without hormone therapy or surgery.

*If* we accept this as authoritative, we may hunker down behind its bastion against the advancing hordes, and disavow/disallow **"transitionable"** in the sense given above.

Comment: Great point and answer (although I have to admit that I wasn't aware of the "transitive/intransitive plus 'able/ible' 'rules'/restrictions" until stumbling across [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15203/is-putting-able-to-any-verb-allowed), especially its accepted and bonus-earning answer, while trying to fully understand [and ultimately appreciate] your answer)!

Answer (score 2):

[Transition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transition) is a noun- it refers to the process of transferring, or to the time period during which a transfer is made.

You should use the word [Transferable.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transferable)

> able to be transferred or made over to the possession of another person

Comment: By the link you yourself provided, transition can in fact be used as a transitive verb: "Undergo or cause to undergo a process or period of transition". So I can't accept this answer purely on the basis of "no, because it's a noun".

Comment: @Dan henderson As you found yourself, transitionable is not used outside mathematics/engineering but "transferable" is widely understood and acceptable in the sense of your  sentence, as in "transferable skills" for example. Why trying using a longer, more awkward word that would not add anything to the sentence?